# _escaped_fragment_ Issue in html5Mode with AngularJS SEO

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to configure my project for SEO. But before that, I need to convert #! characters to _escaped_fragment. I have added a base tag and meta in my head like

```
<base href="/first/index.html" />
<meta name="fragment" content="!">
```

Here first is the name of my project. There are my links.

```
 <li><a href="index.html#!/home">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="index.html#!/about">About</a></li>
 <li><a href="index.html#!/features">Features</a></li>
```

Inside app.config, along with my routing code, I have added this line.

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
```

Its working fine and loading proper views with urls like

1. localhost:63342/first/features
2. localhost:63342/first/home
3. localhost:63342/first/about

But by following these two articles [link1](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-seo-with-prerender-io) and [link2](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/serious-angular-seo.html), our url should be converted from

localhost:3000/#!/signup/page

To

localhost:3000/?_escaped_fragment_=/signup/page

I am unable to convert url like this.

Comment: `_escaped_fragment_` is handled server side... which server are you using?

Comment: I am following the tutorial in the link given above, and using prerender.io.

Comment: I am not even getting #! in the url.

Comment: right, the `#!` is not emitted, because of `html5Mode(true)`.

Comment: You mean #! exist there and server will render it to _escaped_fragment_?

Comment: Actually, I have changed my code a bit and using ui-router now. And my link is like <li><a ui-sref=".home">Home</a></li> with same base url and $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');. It again generate http://localhost:63342/first/home as url. Does #! still exist here??

Comment: I can't explain it any other way.  You **do not** get `#!` **at all** when using `html5Mode(true)`.  This is the entire point of html5Mode.  if you ***manually*** create links that contain `#!`, they will still be routed to the correct route.  If a search engine submits a link with either `#!` or `_escaped_Fragment_` in them, no matter where it got it from, then prerender.io should be kicking in on the server.  it's hard to tell you much more since you still haven't stated which server you are using (prerender.io can be run on many different kinds of servers).